# Set the position and rotation of an image within the excel chart using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am developing a simple excel application to calculate rotation angle of a boat using the moment balance for given tow and propulsion forces. I would like to display the results graphically as shown in the figure below.

[image: Tug boat]

I can draw a simple line drawing and position them in the chart as shown in the left image in yellow, but I would like to have a nice picture of a boat instead.

The same principle will apply for the right hand image where only the rotation will be shown.

For this, I would like to learn how to access the handle of the image and set its location and rotation using a VBA macro.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick test where I was able to rotate an image.

The image (rotated to 0 deg):

[image]

The test code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RotateBoat()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim boatPic As Shape

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set boatPic = ws.Shapes.Item(1)

    '--- rotate the boat
    boatPic.Rotation = 45#

End Sub
```

And the resulting image (rotated to 45 deg):

[image]

Comment: Thanks @PeterT, it worked. Anyway I can know what item number represent which image since I have multiple images in my worksheet. Anyway I can assign name to them and use the name instead? Also, is there a way to choose point of rotation as currently the figure is rotating about the center.

Comment: The [Shape.Rotation Property documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744648.aspx) describes the rotation about the Z-axis. So the rotation point is fixed at the center point of the image. You can certainly assign names to the images, and even better use descriptive variable names in your VBA code for each image.